# Firefox get&change url from Delphi

Tags: delphi, url, firefox

is there a way to get current url typed in Firefox and then based on replay to change that text.
I can find url opened with DDEClient but I don't know how to change it?

Comment: Do you mean by DDEClient Spyglass SDI interface? If yes, have you tried **WWW_OpenURL** command?

Comment: yes I have used that but haven't tried that command yet, didn't even know about it till now.
How do you use it?

Comment: for SDI interface see [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160957](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160957)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many years ago, I used it this way (just a fragment):

```
    ...
    DdeClientConv:=TDdeClientConv.Create(nil);
    try with DdeClientConv do
      begin
        if SetLink(Browser, 'WWW_OpenURL') then
          begin
            PCH := RequestData(Format('"%s",,%d',[AURL,0]));
            if Assigned(PCH) then
              begin
                PD := PDWORDS(PCH);
                if PD^[0]=dword(-3) then
                  ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(),'Open',PChar(AURL),nil,nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                StrDispose(PCH);
              end;
          end
        else
          ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(),'Open',PChar(AURL),nil,nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL)
      end;
    finally
      DdeClientConv.Free;
    end;
    ...
```